# Only one solution at a time in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Simple question here : When I open a new project in Visual studio 2010 ultimate, it closes my current project and opens the new one. I thought it was weird at first but I didn't mind. Now that I'm making tests for my program, it's pretty annoying. While searching for an answer to my problem, I arrived to understand that it was not the default behaviour of the IDE and yet I don't remember changing any settings for this.

In summary, I can't have more than one solution / project in my solution explorer? What am I doing wrong here?

Please help.

Comment: Project or solution? What edition of Visual Studio are you using (Express, Pro, Ultimate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio only supports having one solution open at a time. You can, however, add multiple projects to a single solution via `File > Add > Existing Project...`

Comment: Or, you can have multiple instance of Visual Studio open.

Comment: Absolutely; and opening a second project from Windows Explorer will result in a new instance of Visual Studio being launched. Only when attempting to open an existing project from within an existing Visual Studio instance will it close any opened projects/solutions, replacing them with the one that was selected.